# Unexpected results

Tags: c++

At our organization we recieve a daily blacklist (much bigger as this is just a snippet) in the following format:

> 172.44.12.0
>
> 198.168.1.5
>
> 10.10.0.0
>
> 192.168.78.6
>
> 192.168.22.22
>
> 111.111.0.0
>
> 222.222.0.0
>
> 12.12.12.12

When I run the program after the code compiles I receive:

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1
>
> 1

I am using C++ in a Linux/Unix environment.

So far, I am just spitting it out to make sure I have it formatted correctly.

The name of the file is blacklist.txt which contains the IP's listed above for now.  I am only using cout to make sure my variable are defined correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

using namespace std;

bool is_match(std::string &hay_stack, std::string &srcip) {
    in_addr_t _ip = inet_addr(hay_stack.c_str());
    in_addr_t _IP = inet_addr(srcip.c_str());
    _ip = ntohl(_ip);
    _IP = ntohl(_IP);
    uint32_t mask=(_ip & 0x00ffffff == 0) ? 0xff000000 :
    (_ip & 0x0000ffff == 0 ? 0xffff0000 : 0);
    return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
}

int main()
{
    vector<std::string> lines;
    lines.reserve(5000); //Assuming that the file to read can have max 5K lines

    string fileName("blacklist.txt");

    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        cerr<<"Error opening file : "<<fileName.c_str()<<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Read the lines and store it in the vector
    string line;
    while(getline(file,line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    file.close();

    //Dump all the lines in output
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        string h = lines[i];
        string mi = "10.10.10.10";
        cout<<is_match(h,mi)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the output to be 10.10.10.10 (some sort of host subnet here) 10.10.0.0 (and some sort of subnet mask here)

Comment: I would guess that 'mask' is consistently evaluating to zero.

Comment: Do you have a specific question or should we just fix the program for you?

Comment: Even though you haven't provided a question, I'm still going to +1 for: providing a complete program (http://sscce.org) and using the correct idiom for reading lines of input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where your problem is:

```
uint32_t mask=(_ip & 0x00ffffff == 0) ? 0xff000000 :
(_ip & 0x0000ffff == 0 ? 0xffff0000 : 0);
return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
```

If _ip is in the form x.0.0.0, it only compares x in _IP,
and if _ip is in the form x.y.0.0, it only compares x and y in _IP,
which is fine.

But if _ip isn't in either format you set the mask to 0 <- this is the problem.

When you take (_ip & 0) the result is always 0, likewise with (_IP & 0).
This means you always return true on addresses with a.b.c.d, c != 0 or d != 0.

Instead, make the default mask equal 0xffffffff to check for a complete match.

But it turns out that's not the big problem.  The big problem is that == has a higher operator precedence than &, so your code is actually working like this:

```
uint32_t mask=(_ip & (0x00ffffff == 0)) ? 0xff000000 :
    (_ip & (0x0000ffff == 0) ? 0xffff0000 : 0);
return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
```

As a result, you will always get the 0 for a mask.  You need to apply parens to fix this.

So in conclusion, your code should change to look like this:

```
uint32_t mask=( (_ip & 0x00ffffff) == 0) ? 0xff000000 :
    ( (_ip & 0x0000ffff) == 0 ? 0xffff0000 : 0xffffffff);
return ( (_ip & mask) == (_IP & mask) );
```

Comment: Thanks alot I am new to programming, I have basically spent only hours on learning C ++ so far.

Comment: Thanks alot I am new to programming, I now only recieve all zeros.  Should I not have a different value returned for the match (10.10.10.10 resides within the 10.10.0.0 subnet) so I would expect a different result from the other values that are contained in the blacklist.txt file?

Comment: It turns out there was an even more subtle operation precedence problem.  I've updated my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

*Responding to the implicit question, "Why doesn't my program work the way I expect?"*

> I am expecting the output to be 10.10.10.10 (some sort of host subnet here) 10.10.0.0 (and some sort of subnet mask here)

I don't know why you are expecting that. Your code (if the file opens successfully) only has one print statement in it:

```
cout<<is_match(h,mi)<<endl;
```

The function `is_match` always return a bool, either `true` or `false`. When printed, it will always be either `1` or `0`, respectively. There simply isn't any code in your program which could print an IP address or netmask.

Comment: And since that boolean is always true ... whatever it is he's trying to do in `is_match()` ... isn't working.

Comment: I am trying to take 10.10.10.10 and see if it matches anything in the blacklist.txt.  Since the entries that are a network range do not contain a subnet mask, I am assuming i have to assign a mask to those addresses and see if my host falls in that range.

Comment: I think I just got it.  Changed == to <=.